# How to change SQL WHERE clause through excel?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have build a SQL query to provide me historical price data of a product, which I intent to use in excel (pivot, graphs, all of that fancy excel stuff).

The problem now is that, due to the nature of many products and many price changes, I can not get all the products loaded that I intent to.

I somehow need to tell excel that has to change a couple numbers in the connected SQL query, i.e. through a text box and then load the query again. Otherwise I will always open up the query editor in excel and change it manually, which takes quite a bit.

I reckon I will have to use some sort of macro or VBA, but I have never used it. If anyone could refer an article that would be great, as i could not find anything helpful.

Some code:

```
  WHERE


 PD.Product_Id = '11761476'  < I will have to change that number  


AND

PSPH.[Valid_To] > '2018-01-01'


ORDER BY 
PSPH.[Valid_To]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. * Otherwise I will always open up the query editor in excel and change it manually* Use the macro recorder while you do this, and then adap the code to your needs. Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked! However, is there a way to connect  a Textbox (ActiveX) to the macro? Meaning, that i put number x in the text box and it will change the product id number within the macro?

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate the SQL ***string***, you could do something like this..

```
pid = "11761476"
validto = "2018-01-01"

SQLtemplate = "WHERE PD.Product_Id = '[prodID]' AND PSPH.[Valid_To] > '[validto]' ORDER BY PSPH.[Valid_To]"

Sql = Replace(SQLtemplate, "[prodID]", pid)
Sql = Replace(Sql, "[validto]", validto)
```

but before you can use that, you'll need to follow @Foxfire's advice and record a macro while you're changing it manually to see exactly what needs to change, and how.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this instead in the connection:

```
WHERE
PD.Product_Id = '11761476'  < ? 
AND
PSPH.[Valid_To] > '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY 
PSPH.[Valid_To]
```

And then save the connection.

The first time it will run, a prompt will ask you where to find the parameter, and you can choose the cell.

Let me know if it works!

Cheers,

Arnaud